# How to hide the View tab in user page?

Tags: 7, users

In the user page (www.example.com/user), there are `[View | Edit]` tabs. Is it possible to hide the `View` tab and leave `Edit` tab there?

Comment: For which Drupal version are you asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer), which allows you to move, hide and disable tabs on various pages.

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering, hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab labels.

Answer (score 13):

You could also just use `hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()` in D7:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data){
foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['#link']['path'] == "user/%/view"){
            unset($data['tabs'][0]['output'][$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7)

Comment: Thank you for this nice answer! I added `if($data['tabs'])` before the `foreach` in order to check whether there are any tabs. Otherwise, if that is not the case, one gets an error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the appropriate permission to the user, only then the *view* and *edit* tag will visible otherwise it will not be visible. (For checking you can sign out from the website and click the menu in user page. The view and edit tag will not visible)