# How to add a span before a tabs item?

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I would like to add a little icon before the tab item 'Edit'. Firebug shows that the default code looks like this:

```
<ul class="tabs-primary tabs primary">
  <li class="tabs-primary__tab">
    <a href="/MY_SITE/node/%/edit" class="tabs-primary__tab-link">Edit</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My idea is to add a `span` before the `<a>...</a>`:

```
<ul class="tabs-primary tabs primary">
  <li class="tabs-primary__tab">
    <span class="edit"></span>
    <a href="/MY_SITE/node/%/edit" class="tabs-primary__tab-link">Edit</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

where the edit class has the underneath CSS.

```
.edit {
    background-image: url("MY_IMAGE.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 16px;
}
```

Adding the `<span>` directly with Firebug gives the wanted result, but I don't know how to do this in a template or with a function. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Don't agree with the close vote on this.  The question is perfectly on-topic.  Just because it can be solved in a non-Drupal way doesn't disqualify it.

Comment: To add to what @MPD said, the question says also "I don't know how to do this in a template or with a function." The answer should point out which hook should be used, and this makes the question perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a `<span>` element, you could also use the [::before](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) CSS selector. If a combination with [:first-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) or [:nth-child()](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) is not helpful, most likely you have to implement [`hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7.x) and add a specific class to the desired link(s) (you can add them through attributes in `localized_options` of the `#link` property, see https://api.drupal.org/comment/25393#comment-25393) and then you could use the ::before selector. Or you could implement/overwrite [`theme_menu_local_task()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_local_task/7.x) (probably in combination with a theme preprocess or the earlier mentioned alter function) to add your `<span>` element.

Comment: I suppose you mean that I can use the class `tabs-primary__tab`. But what if there will be several tabs? I don't want to display the same icon in front of all the tabs.

Comment: Is :first-child, in combination with ::before, a solution for you (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)?

Comment: I don't think so either, because by default the first child of the tabs is the View tab, which I've hidden (using http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/77964/16550).

Comment: Ok, if :first-child or :nth-child() are not helpful, most likely you have to implement hook_menu_local_tasks_alter() and add a specific class to the desired link(s) (if I'm not mistaken you can add them through attributes in localized_options of the #link property) and then you could use the ::before selector. Or you could implement/overwrite theme_menu_local_task (probably in combination with a theme preprocess or the earlier mentioned alter function) to add your <span> element.

Answer (score 2):

You can paste code below in your theme file template.php and clear cache

```
function [yourtheme]_menu_local_task($variables) {
  $link = $variables ['element']['#link'];
  $link_text = $link ['title'];

  if (!empty($variables ['element']['#active'])) {
    // Add text to indicate active tab for non-visual users.
    $active = '<span class="element-invisible">' . t('(active tab)') . '</span>';

    // If the link does not contain HTML already, check_plain() it now.
    // After we set 'html'=TRUE the link will not be sanitized by l().
    if (empty($link ['localized_options']['html'])) {
      $link ['title'] = check_plain($link ['title']);
    }
    $link ['localized_options']['html'] = TRUE;
    $link_text = t('!local-task-title!active', array('!local-task-title' => $link ['title'], '!active' => $active));
  }

  return '<li' . (!empty($variables ['element']['#active']) ? ' class="active"' : '') . '><span class="edit"></span>' . l($link_text, $link ['href'], $link ['localized_options']) . "</li>\n";
}
```